# HTTP Status 404 Apache Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am facing a very strange problem. I made my assignment using JavaEE I run it on my local machine and it works fine, when I deploy it on VM it give me the following error. Nothing is changed in the code.

**HTTP Status 404 - /pagescount/start.jsp**

**type Status report**

**message /pagescount/start.jsp**

**description The requested resource is not available**

I dont have any issues in my code on local machine.

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem

Comment: did you deploy using a war file ?

Comment: Did you check in the Manager app?

Comment: Check the Tomcat log for the deployment of your war. Most likely, your application was not deployed correctly, thus there is nothing to serve for the container. To make a blind guess, it might be related to external resources like a database which you have on your local machine but not in the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and help but the problem was in css. I included some css on the top of my index.jsp due to which it was not working... though it is strange

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the inclusion of css in my index.jsp file. Nothing else was wrong. So don't include css in jsp make a style.css file and include it in your jsp.

It solved my problem